# How to prioritize library files order in Run Time

Tags: qtp

I've loaded three library file dynamically using below code. I've overridden few function of A.vbs in B.vbs. So, i want to change the priority order from "A.vbs->B.vbs->C.vbs" to "B.vbs->A.vbs->C.vbs ."

How do i change the priority position of the library file (B.vbs) after executing below code.     it's easy to do ExecuteFile "C:\B.vbs" before "C:\A.vbs" but i need to change the position of library based on user specified input position.

```
ExecuteFile "C:\A.vbs"  
ExecuteFile "C:\B.vbs"  
ExecuteFile "C:\C.vbs"
```

-Shreshtha

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't exactly get why you would want to do that,yet the simplest way would be wrapping your Execute statements inside  if or switch statements based on the User I/p. eg

```
select case choice

case 0 : ExecuteFile "C:\A.vbs" 
         ExecuteFile "C:\B.vbs"
         ExecuteFile "C:\C.vbs"

case 1:  ExecuteFile "C:\B.vbs" 
         ExecuteFile "C:\A.vbs"
         ExecuteFile "C:\C.vbs"
```

and so on.

where "choice" will be an input from the user which will decide the sequence.

If you want the User to give the exact sequence , you could also do something like the below:

```
case "123" : ExecuteFile ... ' Order A, B, C
case "213" : ExecuteFile ... ' Order B, A, C
```

and so on